# what is 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 - 1/6 + 1/7 - 1/8 +1/9 - ...?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that it is converging because it is alternating series with terms getting smaller to zero. but I do not know what it converges to value

Comment: $\ln 2$ $\hspace{0in}$

Comment: It is called the alternating harmonic series.  See the Taylor series expansion of the natural logarithm about $x=1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
S = 1- 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + \ldots = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}dx \quad \Rightarrow
$$
$$
S = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-x)^{n+1}dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1 + x}dx = \log 2
$$

Comment: How did the sum and integral change their order?

Comment: The series has uniform converges in the integration range.

Comment: Why did you multiply by $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n+1}dx=\frac{1}{n+2}$ instead of $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}dx=\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: Indeed, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^{n+1} = \frac{x^2}{1+x}$. I believe it should instead be $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ \mathsf dx$ to obtain the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1+x}$.

Comment: Can you explain how $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ became $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+1} dx$ ?

Answer (score 3):

$ S = 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \dots - \frac{1}{2n} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{2n} - 2 ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \dots + \frac{1}{2n}) =  1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{2n} - 2 \frac{1}{2} ( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... \frac{1}{n} ) $

Call $ H_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... \frac{1}{n} $ the harmonic series
We know that $ H_n - \ln n\,$ converges to the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant)
$\gamma = 0.57...$

$S = H_{2n} - H_n = H_{2n} - \ln{2n} -  H_n + \ln n + \ln 2n - \ln n = (H_{2n} - \ln 2n ) - ( H_n - \ln n ) + ln ( \frac{2n}{n} ) \to \ln( \frac{2n}{n} ) = \ln 2$